# How can I remove the 'fishbowl' effect when creating a square grid on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, grid, graph-theory

I have been trying to create a graph representing a square grid with 8 nodes. I have been using code given by Mathworks [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.graphplot.highlight.html#:%7E:text=highlight%20%28H%2CnodeIDs%29%20highlights%20the%20nodes%20specified%20by%20nodeIDs,the%20edges%20of%20the%20underlying%20graph%20of%20H):

```
n = 8;
A = delsq(numgrid('S',n+2));
G = graph(A,'omitselfloops');
p = plot(G);`
```

The plotted result is:

[image]

But I just wondered if I could make the image less curved. In order to make the graph look more 'uniform' and have all the edges the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph `G` contains no coordinates for the nodes, so MATLAB basically has to "guess" where to put them (and does a remarkably good job). You can use the additional argument `XData`, `YData` (and `ZData`) to add coordinates to your nodes (see [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.html)), so in your case you might want to use e.g `meshgrid`:

```
n = 8; 
A = delsq(numgrid('S',n+2)); 
G = graph(A,'omitselfloops'); 
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:n, 1:n);
p = plot(G, 'XData',x(:), 'YData',y(:));
```